# How to access data from nested dicts json?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I want to get some data from a json file. I can access everything with the code below.

```
import json
    
with open('C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\stdin.json', 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as json_file:
data = json.load(json_file)
    
    
    print("Type: ", type(data))
    print("VM: ", data["Datacenter"])
```

The .json file looks like this:

```
{
   "Datacenter":[
      {
         "Folder":[
            {
               "Folder":[
                  {
                     "VirtualMachine":[
                        {
                           "moid":"vm-239566",
                           "name":"DEV CentOS 6",   
                        },
                        {
                           "moid":"vm-239464",
                           "name":"DEV Sles 12",
                        },
                     ],
                     "moid":"group-v239127",
                     "name":"DEV-VMs"
                  },
               ],
               "moid":"group-v78",
               "name":"Test and Dev"
            },
            {
               "VirtualMachine":[
                  {
                     "moid":"vm-66130",
                     "name":"Hyv16-clone",
                  }
               ],
               "moid":"group-v77",
               "name":"Templates"
            }
         ],
         "moid":"datacenter-21",
         "name":"Datencenter"
      }
   ],
   "vSphereHost":"srv01",
   "vSphereProductLine":"vpx",
   "vSphereServer":"VMware vCenter Server",
   "vSphereVersion":"xxx",
   "version":"1.0",
   "viewType":"VMs and Templates"
}
```

Note that the original json file was much bigger as I deleted lines for readabilty. Also note that I run everything from Command Line, as my IDE always gives me the error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 22910-22912: character maps to <undefined>`

I tried to use `data["VirtualMachine"]` instead of `data["Datacenter"]` but then I get an error... `TypeError: 'VirtualMachine' is an invalid keyword argument for this function.`
So how can I get/print the moid and name of a VM? I am really new to coding and don´t know how to deal with nested dictionarys

Comment: A problem is that you have nested objects that use the same key (`VirtualMachine`) in different places, which would result in conflicting answers. So you may need to clarify from which object you want `moid` and `name` for anyone to give a single answer.

Comment: `VirtualMachine` is part of a `Folder`, which is part of *another* `Folder`, which is part of `DataCenter`.  So you need to drill down one level at a time.

Comment: Also, some of these are *arrays*, whose elements are identified by their position, not by a name (which they don't have).

Comment: `some_dict[key]` and `some_list[index]`; chain as appropriate. Question only becomes somewhat interesting after applying that basic access doesn’t contain the result and/or becomes messy to check.

Comment: FWIW: that error should not come from the _presented_ code. Validate again and update the question.

Comment: I want to access name and void for "DEV CentOS 6"

Comment: I will update the question  tomorrow!

Comment: Updated it, note that I run everything from Command Line. The error presented is still KeyError: 'VirtualMachine'

Answer (score 0):

However your question does not seems clear but from whatever you have mentioned this can be help you deriving the value in nested json if you have already have dataframe created. You can go ahead and add `get()` till you reach what you require. Below is the sample that you can use

```
import json
data = data.apply(lambda x: json.loads(json.loads(x).get("Folder","{}")).get("moid") if x else None)
```